# Rethink DB - Data Explorer

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I am pretty un-advanced with computer in general, however am using RethinkDB to store data. I am using data explorer on the platform  to query and filter information I want, however want to query and search two or three tables in one query. Is this possible?For example I can input this query r.db('locations').table('twitter'), but in addition would want to add in r.db('locations').table('instagram') and even r.db('smarta').table('facebook') all in the one output. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union` to combine tables: `r.db('locations').table('instagram').union(r.db('locations').table('twitter'))`.